# Optimum Location for Code Schools

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, distance

This is taken from Code wars, but I am not looking for cheat or anything. I have pretty much solved the problem but I'm unsure if my method of determining what constitutes as best location is correct.

```
var optimumLocation = function(students, locations){
  //your solution
  var listOfLocations = [];  
  for (var key in locations) {
    var obj = locations[key];
    var totalDistance = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= students.length-1; i+=1) {
      console.log(students[i]);
      var location = calculateDistance(students[i],[obj.x, obj.y]);
      totalDistance += location;
    }

    listOfLocations.push({id:parseInt(key), dist:totalDistance});

  }

  listOfLocations.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.dist - b.dist;
  });

  console.log(listOfLocations);
  var id = listOfLocations[0].id;
  return "The best location is number " + (id +1) + " with the coordinates x = " + locations[id].x + " and y = " + locations[id].y;
}

function  calculateDistance (loc1, loc2) {
  var distX = Math.abs(loc1[0] - loc2[0]);
  var distY = Math.abs(loc1[1] - loc2[1]);


  var distance = Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY);

  return distance;

};
```

For the first test case

```
optimumLocation([[3,7],[2,2],[14,1]],[{id: 1, x: 3, y: 4}, {id: 2, x: 8, y: 2}]);
```

everything is fine.

But for the second test case

```
optimumLocation([[152,7],[1,211],[14,56],[12,4],[142,7]],[{id: 1, x: 63, y: 55}, {id: 2, x: 55, y: 21},{id: 3, x: 144, y: 12}]);
```

The correct location is location 2 but my function thinks it is location 1. However with my method of using the least total distance for all students to travel, location 1 has the lowest and therefore should actually be the optimum solution over location 2.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to figure this out myself. For those who are wondering, I simply over complicated the problem. The question stated that students could only walk in straight lines, not diagonally. So instead of using pythagoras theorem, I simply had to add the x and y distances together to find the total distance.